# TFS Build template consuming WCF web service throws config error

Tags: web-services, tfs, build, config

The error I get when I run my build looks like this.
"Exception Message: Could not find endpoint element with name'BasicHttpBinding_IR..." and contract 'IR...Service' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching ".

I have two workflow activity library projects for this build, a templates project and a custom activities project. The purpose of this build is to deploy sql scripts from TF so does not actually build a project.

I referenced a wcf web service in an Activities library project I use for custom activites. It created a bunch of xaml files related to methods of the service.
In my templates (activities library) project I was able to drag my web service activities onto my template, I added the one I needed and gave it a return variable. The endpoint configuration name was set to the end point name in the .config file in the activities project. All good.
The build runs correctly up to the point it needs to call the web service and throws the above error.
My questions are. Where should I expect the .config file to be that is used by the build process that is running my build? Is there any information / blogs / msdn reference out there that deals with this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it will be easy or...consistant to try and put the config files somewhere. The better option would be to manually code up the properties by creating instances off the required configuration objects and passing them in. You can then set things like the endpoint as variables in your workflow.

I have a blog post from way back in 2007 on how to create a WCF host programmatically: http://nakedalm.com/creating-wcf-service-host-programmatically/

While this is the wrong end (the host instead of the client) it demonstrates how to create the configuration objects programmatically.

Comment: It would be part of your custom activity...so all in code. Then you can just configure a standard Workflow input variable. How are you coding it now?

Comment: I'm not the OP. I would have no problem writing such an activity. But maybe future readers would like an example.